# TestNG - Exception only when 6 or more tests are defined

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, testng

The code below fails, but only if 6 or more Tests are defined. That is, no matter what tests I have. I have tried making 5 duplicate tests, which all passed,and then add another one to see the assertion below fail. **Does anyone have an idea what's going on?**

I run Spring MVC, TestNG Version 5.8, with a Neo4J database using Spring Data Graph.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml"})
public class EntityTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private GraphDatabaseContext graphDatabaseContext;

    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(graphDatabaseContext);
    }

    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void testEmployeeCreation() throws Exception {
       //please note that these methods are _literally_ empty.
    }

    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void test2EmployeeCreation() throws Exception {
    }
    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void test3EmployeeCreation() throws Exception {
    }
    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void test4EmployeeCreation() throws Exception {
    }
    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void test5EmployeeCreation() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test(groups = {"functest"})
    public void test6EmployeeCreation() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

testNG.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Maven Tests" verbose="1" annotations="JDK">

    <parameter name="echo.timeout" value="60000"/>

    <test name="Functional and Check-in Tests">

        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="functest"/>
                <include name="checkintest"/>
            </run>
        </groups>

        <classes>
            <class name="com.noname.entity.EntityTest"/>
        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

Testlog:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false

    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:84)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:438)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:32)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:352)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:342)
    at com.noname.entity.EntityTest.setUp(EntityTest.java:25)
```

Comment: Could you please post the complete Test class, because this part does obviously not contain the problem. And by the way is there any kind of singleton or static field that may causes the problem?

Comment: Is the exception because the `assertNotNull` fails, or is it a spring exception? -- In the second case, please post the exception and stacktrace too.

Comment: @Ralph: There you go! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The database context isn't used in these simple tests. What happens if you remove it? Would something else break? What's in your XML config?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a problem like this, the first thing you think of is whether some resource is being used up (such as database connections or open files).  Check to see if removing `graphDatabaseContext` makes a difference.  Admittedly when looking at the api for `GraphDatabaseContext` and `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` I don't see any obvious case of a reference needing to be released, but maybe someone more familiar with the classes can take it from there.